# How to extract specified numbers from a HTML source and merge them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

There is a site that gives 3 numbers as pictures that you have to copy and write in a specified box and press continue.I want to write a code to do it for me.I looked at the HTML source and the png files are named same as the number so I just need to extract them ,merge and write it down.

I've used Selenium to make a bot and access the site after I login it fills the specified area with "123" as a test so I know how to write down the numbers if I somehow get them.I used Beatifulsoup to turn it into text for but it gave me an error

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\money.py", line 20
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver)
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 20 of the file C:\Users\user\Desktop\money.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\money.py", line 20, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 287, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'WebDriver' has no len()
```

I'd appreciate if you have a different method or can fix the issue.
I haven't figured out how to press the continue button automatically but will press it myself if needed.
My code not even close to being done so feel free to suggest anything.

````
import time
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Personal/PythonScripts/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('URL I USED')

time.sleep(20)
driver.refresh()
try :
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input').send_keys('123')
except :
    print('Fail')


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver ,"lxml")

images = list()
try :
 re.findall(r'\d+', soup)
 images.append(new)
except:
    print('Fail')
html_source = driver.page_source
print(html_source)```
````

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you forgot `.page_source`  in `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")`

Comment: Thanks a bunch.I don't if I should make a new post but how can I extract the number 6 from "<img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/6.png">".The number always ranges between 1 -9 and there is 3 of them I need to write in one specified box.(I wrote a little about this in the post)

Comment: `The code that caused this warning is on line 20 of the file C:\Users\user\Desktop\money.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.` this line is giving you the hint. Always pay attention to the traceback messages.

Comment: .I had "lxml" in the code already but the error persisted but after I added what @furas told me,they both disappeared

Comment: to get number use beautifulsoup to `find()` `img` and get attribute `src` and then you can use  `text[-5]` to get char from text

Comment: Have you read the docs for Selenium and BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `.page_source` in `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")`

---

As for numebers if you use `BeautifulSoup` then use all of its functionality - use `find_all()` to find all `<img>` and get attributes `src`. And then you can get char from `src` (which is string) as `string[-5]`

if there are more images then you could use other attributes in `find_all()` - ie. `width="35"`

You should read documentation for [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) - it has many useful functions.

---

```
html = '''<img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/6.png">
<img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/3.png">
<img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/1.png">'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(html, 'lxml')

all_items = soup.find_all('img')
#all_items = soup.find_all('img', width='35')
for item in all_items:
    print('char:', item['src'][-5])

number = [item['src'][-5] for item in all_items]
number = "".join(number)

print('number:', number)
```

Result

```
char: 6
char: 3
char: 1
number: 631
```

---

You could do this even without `BeautifulSoup` because `Selenium` has many function `find_elements_by_...` (ie. `find_elements_by_xpath()`) and it has also `get_attribute()`

Read Selenium documentation: [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), [get_attribute](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

Not tested

```
all_items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for item in all_items:
    print('char:', item.get_attribute('src')[-5])

number = [item.get_attribute('src')[-5] for item in all_items]
number = "".join(number)

print('number:', number)
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say I found some issues with this really well-written code.I used it and the url sent back few more than expected.It gave back few letters.I removed them by passing them by a code to test if they are numbers.My only issue left now is to refresh the page everytime to get the new numbers and click the button.I'm thinking of looping the code for the former issue.Thank you for the quick and helpful answer.

Comment: it happens when you don't show real url in question - we can't see real HTML and we can't create code which resolve all problems. As I said in answer - maybe you can use other attributes to find only images with numbers. To refresh page you can use again `driver.get(your_url)` or send JavaScript code like `driver.execute_script('document.location=your_url')`

Comment: Not to worry as I already found a solution for it.I progressed alot further thanks to your help but I still have some obstacles.I can describe it as the numbers that were generated were correct but on the next "survey" my program writes down the previously made number.I added some sleep time to no avail.I can make new post unless you can help me out once more.

Comment: create new question on new page - you will have more space for description and code. And new people will see it so maybe someone else will help you.